# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined NodeJS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I got images with same width and height and `onclick` they should get bigger, so I made an function with an `eventlistener` for it but now it tells me that style isn't defined and I don't see the issue. I set the styles inside the `img` tag and also without style.

```
<img class="painting" src="<%= post.paintingsP %>" />
    <img class="painting" style="max-width: 20%; min-width: 300px; height: 250px;"src="<%= post.paintingsP2 %>" />
```

js file

```
const paint = document.getElementsByClassName('painting');
let flag = true;

for (var i = 0; i < paint.length; i++) {
    paint[i].style.maxWidth = '20%';
    paint[i].style.height = '250px';
    paint[i].style.minWidth = '300px';

    paint[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (flag == true && window.innerWidth >= 769) {
            paint[i].style.maxWidth = '95vw';
            paint[i].style.height = 'auto';

            flag = false;
        } else if (flag == true && window.innerWidth < 769) {

        } else {
            paint[i].style.maxWidth = '20%';
            paint[i].style.minWidth = '300px';
            paint[i].style.height = 'auto';
            flag = true;
        }
    })
}
```

If I try to use `getelementById` everything works fine but I don't want for every image an `eventlistener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.target` in the eventlistener function to find the clicked image.

```js
const paint = document.getElementsByClassName('painting');
let flag = true;

for (var i = 0; i < paint.length; i++) {

    paint[i].style.maxWidth = '20%';
    paint[i].style.height = '250px';
    paint[i].style.minWidth = '300px';

    paint[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log(event.target)
        if (flag == true && window.innerWidth >= 769) {
           event.target.style.maxWidth = '95vw';
           event.target.style.height = 'auto';

            flag = false;
        } else if (flag == true && window.innerWidth < 769) {

        } else {
            event.target.style.maxWidth = '20%';
            event.target.style.minWidth = '300px';
            event.target.style.height = 'auto';
            flag = true;
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<img class="painting" src="<%= post.paintingsP %>" />
    <img class="painting" style="max-width: 20%; min-width: 300px; height: 250px;"src="<%= post.paintingsP2 %>" />
```